# C:\platform-tools>adb install FirstGo.apk Performing Streamed Install Error: Requires newer sdk version #29 (current version is #25)]

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, adb

So now I know that I need to change the minimum SDK from 29 to 25 if I want to support my older device.

So then I did this from within Unity:
"To export your Unity Project as a Gradle project, enable the Export Project setting, and then select the Export button. When you do this, Unity generates a Gradle project in the folder you specify, and doesn’t build an .apk file. Import this project into Android Studio or another external tool to make further changes, or to build it from there."

And now I see the build.gradle file within Android Studio when I open the project.  This was not the case previously.
So now I can make the change to the build.gradle file where I change the minSdkVersion from 29 to 25.

############

So here is my question.  After I make this change in the build.gradle file, what is my next step?
I think there must be more steps I am missing…. compiling?? building ??

I actually tried to install the project again after only doing the editing above, but, of course, I did not see any different results.

Not being that familiar with the build.gradle file, I am not sure what to do next.
Any help would be most appreciated.